# What pseudonyms / pictographs are appropriate for identifying popular theological personalities?

Tags: discussion, answers

Personally, I am opposed to any form of strangeness on the Internet that makes it a less hospitable and self-idiomatic place. But as a lark, and because this was rolling around in my brain what would be some good "other names" that we could use to identify certain saints, theologians, poets and goodly housewives?

---

Please CW your answers and do one per faith tradition (i.e. Orthodox, Catholic, Reformed etc...)  unless your Church objects to pseudonyms, then please ignore this post with my humblest apologies.

Answer (score 1):

### Catholicism

- St. Therese of Lisieux

  The Little Flower
  [image: Little Flower]
- St. Thomas Aquinas

  The Ox[image: The Ox]
- St. Francis of Assisi

  Brother Ass[image: Brother Ass]
- Gilbert Keith Chesterton

  Uncle Chestnut [image: Uncle Chestnut]

Comment: Oddly enough, I run in circles where St. Francis' moniker applies to Brian McLaren. May have dis ambiguities problems with that one.

Comment: i can put some birds on the donkey's ears